# PHP - Save <Select> tag selected value data of html control

Tags: php, html

I have to build a issue book system. My BookName contains spaces in it.
Below is the php code for filling select control:

```
<?php

    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());  
    mysql_select_db('lms') or die("cannot select DB");  

    $rs = mysql_query("Select bookname from  books");

    $bookname=" "; 

  if (mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {

        $bookname .='<option value='.$row['bookname'].'>'. $row['bookname']. 
  '</option>';
        $bookname= str_replace("_", " ",$bookname);

    }
}
echo $bookname;
mysqli_close($con);
echo "</select><br/>";

<?php 
   if(isset($_POST["submit"])){  
       if(!empty($_POST['issuedate']) && !empty($_POST['expirydate']) ) 
        {  
            $bookname=$_POST['bookname'];
            $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());  
            mysql_select_db('lms') or die("cannot select DB");    
        }
   }
?>
```

The bookname variable doesn't return full book value it returns
My as bookname instead of My Name

Answer (score 0):

You should always put quotes around attribute values. It's absolutely necessary if the value contains spaces (as well as some other special characters).

```
   $bookname .='<option value="'.$row['bookname'].'">'. $row['bookname'].
```

'';